# In MobX, why are side effects bad in render functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, side-effects

Recently I was asked:

> Why can't I write to mobx state in a render function

I know Mobx disallows it, and it isn't good, however I also know you can get around Mobx's check simply by waiting a bit, for example: `Promise.resolve().then(() => observable.value = "test")`.

I've had bad experiences with debugging code in other frameworks when programmers caused side effects in functional functions (render-like functions). However, most of my bad experiences involve really complicated bugs I still don't fully understand, so I couldn't come up with a simple explanation of why this is bad.

In the end I gave a fairly terrible answer, and just told the other programmer:

> It's bad, just trust me, don't try to do that, it'll cause problems later on

**What is a better answer to the question 'why can't I write to mobx state in a render function'?**

---

**NOTES:**

I am specifically interested in any concrete examples of code that would fail (unexpectedly) from this.

I created an example of code that mutates Mobx state within render functions. Each component sets the global curPageName.value state when rendered, and displays this variable, and a different component also displays this variable. It's rather terrifying, but it technically works: https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-playground-u8per?file=/src/index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { observable } from "mobx";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

let curPageName = observable({
  value: "test"
});

const Test = observer(() => {
  Promise.resolve().then(() => (curPageName.value = "Test"));
  return <div>{curPageName.value}</div>;
});
const Test2 = observer(() => {
  Promise.resolve().then(() => (curPageName.value = "Test2"));
  return <div>{curPageName.value}</div>;
});

@observer
class MainPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    page: Test
  };
  render() {
    let Page = this.state.page;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>Cur Page: {curPageName.value}</div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.setState({ page: Test })}>Test</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.setState({ page: Test2 })}>Test2</button>
        </div>
        <Page />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<MainPage />, rootElement);
```

Comment: You don't really need to use `Promise.resolve` thing at all when hooks exists. Just use `useEffect` with empty dependency array, it is specifically created for your use case and side effects. When using classes it is more idiomatically to use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method though, because you can't use hooks with classes..

Comment: I did not know about the `useEffect` function, that is good to know about. It feels like it would be bad practice to trigger other components to render from inside useEffect, but writing to the document.title seems like a good usecase for it.